# Prevent JavaScript from changing the time to GMT

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time

The following outputs a time that is 4 hours less than what was input:

```js
X = new Date('2015-07-09T14:18:12.430')
$('body').append(X)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it's work fine for me :  `Thu Jul 09 2015 14:18:12`, show me your output please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: You haven't specified a timezone in your string, in this case it's being interpreted as `+0000` because it's in the _ISO 8601_ format. The _toString_ method of _Date_ instances will output your local time

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki your local time is GMT so you're not seeing a transformation

Answer (score 1):

When you omit the timezone information on the end of an *ISO 8601* formatted date-time the majority of computer implementations default to `+0000`, this means *Date* interprets `2015-07-09T14:18:12.430` the same as `2015-07-09T14:18:12.430+0000` or `2015-07-09T14:18:12.430Z`

It looks like you were expecting it to be interpreted as your local time rather than in UTC, you have 3 options

1. Append your local timezone offset to the end
2. Write it differently so it will parse as you expect
3. Create a second *Date* using the details from the UTC fields of the first *Date*

```
function myParser(iso_style) {
    var d = new Date(iso_style);
    return new Date(
        d.getUTCFullYear(),
        d.getUTCMonth(),
        d.getUTCDate(),
        d.getUTCHours(),
        d.getUTCMinutes(),
        d.getUTCSeconds(),
        d.getUTCMilliseconds()
    );
}
```

You can't simply adjust by your local offset as you would experience unexpected behaviour if the time crosses a date that would change that offset e.g. a daylight savings boundry

---

As [Salman A](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87015/salman-a)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31327129/1615483) points out the current [*ES 6 Draft*](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-date-time-string-format) defines that an omitted timezone should be interpreted as meaning the client's local timezone. This will make the behaviour inconsistent as different *JavaScript* implementations change over so I strongly recommend you **always** use a timezone when writing *ISO 8601*.

Answer (score 1):

When you do no specify the timezone:

[ECMAScript-5 compliant browsers will assume UTC timezone](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15):

> The value of an absent time zone offset is "`Z`".

[ECMAScript-6 compliant browsers will assume local timezone](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-date-time-string-format):

> If the time zone offset is absent, the date-time is interpreted as a
>   local time.

---

Use the [**long** Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax) which assumes local timezone:

```js
var X = new Date(2015, 7 - 1, 9, 14, 18, 12, 430);
alert(X);
```

Comment: Yeah, you gotta love how JavaScript is 0 based.

Comment: @Phillip Lots of languages use `0`-based months, _JavaScript_, _Java_, _C_. It comes from that computers start counting from `0` and often people want the month name. It's similar with the day of the week being `0` (_Sunday_) to `6` (_Saturday_). Personally I would prefer it to be consistent though, as months are the "odd one out" in the constructor.

Comment: If _ES 6_ stays like this until it's out of draft it will make the behaviour inconsistant as implementations change so I strongly recommend you use a timezone when writing _ISO 8601_

Comment: How do I use a timezone in the input string?

Comment: Oh, it looks like all I have to do is add -04:00 to the end of my string! Yay!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>A quick and dirty workaround:</strike>

```
X = new Date('2015-07-09T14:18:12.430');
$('body').append( X.toString().split('GMT')[0] );
```

It works by turning the date object into a string, then splitting it into an array around the pattern `GMT`. So you would have 2 elements in the array: `Thu Jul 09 2015 10:18:12` and `0400 (EDT)`. Since you want to drop everything after the GMT, you just use the element in the 0 index of the array

I misunderstood the question. If you use X.toUTCString(), it may fix your issue.

Comment: It sill says 10:18 even though I input 14:18.

Comment: @Phillip I misread the question. Converting it to UTC makes it so that the time zone doesn't effect it